# Changing hibernate batch size programmatically

Tags: hibernate

Is possible to change hibernate.jdbc.batch_size programmatically? I understand
hibernate.jdbc.batch_size is a application level parameter, wanted to know if I can use it 
specifically for certain HQL inserts and not others. I would change the code only for those HQL inserts

The big picture is that I need to introduce batch inserts to make the web application performant in some scenarios, but I do not want to jeopardize the normal inserts which work right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't change the configuration settings of a `SessionFactory` at runtime (the settings are not exposed via the public API and are immutable).

In other words, I would use another `SessionFactory` (and set the `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` property in the `Configuration` object used to build it) in the specific scenarios needing it.

Comment: Thanks. This resonates with my understanding. I tested the application. Non bulk inserts work fine as before

Answer (score 2):

From this [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-the-jdbc-batch-size-for-each-persistence-context-with-hibernate/):

> Hibernate 5.2 adds support for customizing the JDBC batch size at the
> Persistence Context level

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
        .setJdbcBatchSize(10)
```